# Cracking noise when launching vehicle or at lower gear

Tags: noise, nissan, drivetrain, x-trail

I have a Nissan X-Trail 2002 manual with almost 300k on it. I know it's old, but it was the only secondhand manual SUV I could find.

The last service was about than 3 months ago. I drove it into a large puddle of water the other day. Next morning, I noticed that the car makes this deep clicking/cracking sound when it starts moving from a complete stop. It clicks somewhere one or two times before the car gains some speed. I can also hear it when I'm cruising on 1st or 2nd gear. A few clicks every time I press down on the gas. It doesn't make the noise if I go really gently, but then I'd annoy the other cars on the road. To put it bluntly, the noise sounds like an iceberg/glacier cracking. The deep "Tut Tut" sound.

At first, after doing my research, I suspected that it was the engine mount. So, I opened up the hood and revved up the engine by using my hand. The engine jerked a bit, but it just seemed normal. I should be able to hear the noise when I rev up the engine on neutral after all if it was the engine mount.

The car drives fine and feels the same. No dashboard light. I'm just worried about the noise. The noise is not heard when the car is moving above 40-50km/h. No noise when braking. Just when accelerating/dragging due to high rpm. I think it's some component along the drive train that makes the noise because the noise is heard when torque is applied.

Obviously, I'll take it to the mechanic, but they're fully booked at the moment.

Comment: The mechanic had a look and said it was bushings/engine mount. All rubbers worn and cracked. I asked if I could get them fixed, but he said it's not worth it("No, I won't do that"). The noise was gone after the service anyway.